# Upper bounding a tricky sum

Tags: probability, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, approximation

For a problem in probability, I'm trying to find an upper bound for

$$ \sum_{d=0}^k\binom{k}{d}\gamma^d(1-\gamma)^{k-d}\left(1-p^d(1-p)^{k-d}\right)^m$$

which will help me analyze what values of $k$, $m$ and $p$ are needed to make the sum go to 0. (Note $0< p,\gamma<1$ and $k$ and $m$ are integers.)

I have tried to approximate the inner part of the right parenthesis using the exponential function, and the binomial part using a normal distribution, but the $p^d$s seem to stand in the way for this approach.

If I expand the parenthesis, I can rewrite the sum as

$$ \sum_{l=0}^m\binom{m}{l}(-1)^l\left(\gamma p^l+(1-\gamma)(1-p)^l\right)^k$$

But that doesn't help me much.

I've run out of ideas to proceed, do you know any good tricks I should check out?

Comment: Since this is a probability question, do we know that $0 \le p, \gamma \le 1$? And what do you mean by "make the sum go to 0"? Are you trying to find values that make the sum = 0, are you wanting the sum to go to 0 asymtotically as $m \to \infty$?

Comment: Have you tried finding an upper bound for the expression that is raised to the $m$-th power?

Comment: @PaulSinclair you are right, I'd like to find the smallest $m$ necessary, like $m= 2^k/p$ or so, to make the sum go to 0 as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon The best upper bound I can get is $1$.

Comment: For instance, $(1-p^d(1-p)^{k-d})^m \le (1-q^k)^m$ where $q= \min\{p,1-p\}$.

Comment: Quick comments: if $k,p$ are fixed and $m\to\infty$, then the expression goes to $0$ as long as $p\ne0,1$. On the other hand, if $m,p$ are fixed and $k\to\infty$, then the expression goes to $1$: only the terms between $k\frac\gamma2$ and $k(1-\frac\gamma2)$ contribute significantly to the sum, and for those terms, the factor in parentheses is at least $(1-(\frac12)^{k\gamma/2})^m$ which tends to $1$.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon Ah, I hadn't tried that! I don't think I can entirely discard $d$, but $(1-x)^n\le1/(1+nx)$ seems to work very well. Except it doesn't let me evaluate the sum..

Comment: Sketch of solution: without the factor in parentheses, the maximal summands occur around $d=\gamma k$. For these terms, the factor in parentheses is around $(1-\alpha^k)^m$, where $\alpha=p^\gamma(1-p)^{1-\gamma}$. You'll need $m>(\frac1\alpha)^k$ just to make that factor in parentheses less than $e$ or so; more precisely, I'm guessing forcing $m\alpha^k\to\infty$ is both necessary and sufficient to make the sum go to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and $\beta \in (0, \infty)$ as

$$ \alpha = p^{\gamma}(1-p)^{1-\gamma} \quad \text{and} \quad \beta = \frac{p}{1-p}. $$

Also we write $X = X_k \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(k, \gamma)$ and denote the sum by $S = S_{m,k}$. Then we can write

$$ S = \Bbb{E}[ (1 - \alpha^k \beta^{X-k\gamma} )^m ]. \tag{1} $$

Since $p^X (1-p)^{k-X} \leq \max \{p, 1-p\}^k \to 0$ uniformly as $k \to \infty$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have

$$ \exp(-(1+\epsilon)\color{red}{\alpha^k \beta^{X-k\gamma}})
\leq 1 - \color{red}{\alpha^k \beta^{X-k\gamma}}
\leq \exp(-\color{red}{\alpha^k \beta^{X-k\gamma}}) $$

whenever $k$ is sufficiently large. Now consider $m$ as a sequence of $k$ and write $a_k = m \alpha^k$. Then this inequality implies

$$ \Bbb{E}[\exp(-(1+\epsilon)a_k \beta^{X-k\gamma})]
\leq S
\leq \Bbb{E}[\exp(-a_k \beta^{X-k\gamma})] \tag{2} $$

for large $k$.

If $\gamma$ and $p$ are fixed, then we can find a condition for $m = m_k$ which guarantees $S \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.

> **Claim.** $S = S(m_k, k)$ converges to $0$ if and only if $m_k \alpha^k r^{\sqrt{k}} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$ for any $r > 0$.

### Sufficient condition

Consider first the case $\beta \leq 1$. Let $x \in \Bbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Then by (2),

\begin{align*}
S
&\leq \Bbb{E}[ \exp ( -a_k \beta^{X-\gamma k} ) \mathbf{1}_{\{ (X-\gamma k)/\sqrt{k} < x\}} ] \\
&\qquad +\Bbb{E}[ \exp ( -a_k \beta^{X-\gamma k} ) \mathbf{1}_{\{ (X-\gamma k)/\sqrt{k} \geq x\}} ] \\
&\leq \exp( -a_k \beta^{x\sqrt{k}} ) + \Bbb{P}((X-\gamma k)/\sqrt{k} \geq x).
\end{align*}

Combining the assumption and the classical CLT, this gives an estimate to the limsup of $S$ as follows :

$$ \limsup_{k\to\infty} S \leq \Phi(-x/\sqrt{\smash[b]{\gamma(1-\gamma)}}), $$

where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. Now taking $x \to \infty$ we get the desired conclusion when $\beta \leq 1$. The other case $\beta \geq 1$ can be treated similarly, and we omit the proof.

### Necessary condition

Again let us focus on the case $\beta \leq 1$. Let $r > 0$ be arbitrary, and let $x = \log r / \log \beta$. Then by (2),

\begin{align*}
S
&\geq \Bbb{E}[ \exp(-(1+\epsilon)a_k \beta^{X-k\gamma}) \mathbf{1}_{\{ (X-\gamma k)/\sqrt{k} \geq x \}} ] \\
&\geq \exp(-(1+\epsilon)a_k r^{\sqrt{k}}) \Bbb{P}((X-\gamma k)/\sqrt{k} \geq x).
\end{align*}

Rearranging everything w.r.t. $a_k r^{\sqrt{k}}$, we get

$$ a_k r^{\sqrt{k}} \geq \frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\log \left( \frac{\Bbb{P}((X-\gamma k)/\sqrt{k} \geq x)}{S} \right) . $$

From the classical CLT and the assumption, the right-hand side diverges to $+\infty$ as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Great thinking splitting the sum up by cases like that! I learned a lot from studying this answer.